# How to make curved header view in React Native?

Tags: css, react-native, view, scrollview

Why some people make it duplicate? I I said that was my question...

First, I own this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60219563/how-to-make-curved-header-view-in-react-native) and now I want to show a better example of my question. Honestly, I didn't try the answer yet because **I'm curious** is there anyway to solved this by code? Well, is it even possible? Besides, using an image as a background to solve this would be a problem, no? I mean, the user's phone is not always has the same screen size.

Here's an example of the idle state of my home screen. I got header with search bar and an horizontal scrollview of image banner. As you can see, if you notice, the banner is overlapping on the top of blue square and a curved blue view.

[image]

And what happen is user scrolled down? Here:

[image]

The curved view and banner is scrolled up. So, how do I achieve this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a png file, with transparent background and this curved border.
Then, set this file as ImageBackground of your header.